# Ignore file changed as part of previous commit

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a reusable workflow called `maven-workflow.yaml`. My repo structure is as below:

```
├───app2
│   └───index
├───src
│   └───main
└───app1
|    └───index
|---README.md
```

My workflow is as below:

```
name: ci
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'main'
    paths:
      - 'src/**'
      - '!*.MD'
      - '!app*/*' 

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: false

jobs:
  ci:
    uses: .github/workflows/maven-workflow.yaml@main
    with:
      java: 17
```

If all the commits I make in the branch are in `app*` folders or `README.MD`, then the workflow is not triggered. But if in between a commit happened to `src` folder, then workflow is run, now for the subsequent commits even if not in `src` folder also triggers the workflow, because a commit has already occurred in `src` before. is there any way this can be ignored?

Comment: It looks at the file changes for the _pull request_, not each individual commit.